# Adding system Python 2.7 back to Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I accidentally deleted the pre-installed system Python 2.7 interpreter from the "Project Interpreter" section in the "Preferences" tab in PyCharm.

How can I add it back?

Comment: I remember there being a plus sign somewhere on that [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html), then you can input the full path to where Python is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an Interpreter, Go To Settings->Project Interpreter:

[image]

Select the Gear in the Top Right:

[image]

Select Add Local:

[image]